# C# HTML Table Button not visible

Tags: c#, html

I have created a table from a class using a string builder that takes the data from a data table. Now I added a HTML button inside a field named 'Stadium Name' and it is not showing up.

Here is my code:

```
  StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

            html.Append("<table border = '1'>");

            html.Append("<tr>");

            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                html.Append("<th>");
                html.Append(column.ColumnName);
                html.Append("</th>");
            }
            html.Append("</tr>");

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                html.Append("<tr>");
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    html.Append("<td>");
                    if (column.ColumnName != "Stadium Name")
                    {
                        html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                    }
                    // PROBLEM STARTS HERE
                    if (column.ColumnName == "Stadium Name")
                    {
                        HtmlButton b = new HtmlButton();                       
                        b.ID = "btnSname";
                        b.InnerText = row[column.ColumnName].ToString();
                        b.ServerClick += new EventHandler(btnSname_Click); 

                    }    
                    // PROBLEM ENDS HERE             

                    html.Append("</td>");                    

                }
                html.Append("</tr>");
            }

            html.Append("</table>");

            return html;
```

Now the data under the column stadium name is empty.

Comment: If you are serving this as part of an asp.net page you are probably over-complicating things a lot by creating literal html - have you considered using a DataList or Repeater control instead?

Answer (score 2):

You are not appending `b` to `html` anywhere. Also, this approach will not work, because even if you successfully serialize `b` to html code and append it to `html`, you will lose your event receiver.

What you can do instead is add a `Table` control on your page (Are you doing Web Forms?) and dynamically add controls to it from the backend, similar to what you are doing now.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0ce8sc.aspx#CodeExamples

Even better and simpler - can you bind your data directly to a GridView?

Comment: Is there an alternative way to achieve the same thing but making the data under stadium names a button with event handler?

Comment: I could bind it to gridview if i want to but i find that easy so i wanted to do it differently

Comment: Oh... (I'd write just that but SO wouldn't let me)

Comment: I am thinking of industrial level of programming. In companies, do you think i would be using gridviews?

Comment: You are right. In a real industry code you will construct the HTML manually, literal tag by tag, just like you are doing it here. The industry demands error-prone, un-maintainable code.

Comment: Yeah its difficult so I am trying to prepare for what I might face when I am working out there. It's hard to remember all these stuff though ^_^